# Nagios Slide View for Different clients

Tags: web

We have different telecom clients and  installed Nagios in all the environments.

**Here is the my Question :**

Can we monitor all these Nagios into single monitor and it should be slideshow like first two minutes one client and next 2 two minutes next client....

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Nagios. All you're really wanting to do is display a rotating set of web pages, correct? If so, several options are discussed over on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699313/automatically-cycle-through-web-pages).

Answer (score 1):

If displaying the web interface of Nagios is not a requirement but a mean to show the status of your alerts, maybe an elegant solution would be to use [`nagstamon`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nagstamon/), available on Linux, Windows, Solaris, BSD, OSX, etc.

You can register multiple Nagios hosts and relevant alerts will show up in its interface (you can even filter out some annoying alerts) (screenshot courtesy of official `nagstamon` website) :

[screenshot http://nagstamon.ifw-dresden.de/files/cache/94a3a50a7c9b98f3f32baef3c9c3b448_f29.png](http://nagstamon.ifw-dresden.de/files/cache/94a3a50a7c9b98f3f32baef3c9c3b448_f29.png)